# How to get a 'stack based' std::stack? (with fixed max size)

Tags: c++, stack, c++17

According to `std::stack` reference:

> The type of the underlying container to use to store the elements.
>   The container must satisfy the requirements of SequenceContainer.
>   Additionally, it must provide the following functions with the usual
>   semantics:
>
> ```
> back()
> push_back()
> pop_back()
> ```
>
> The standard containers std::vector, std::deque and std::list satisfy
>   these requirements. By default, if no container class is specified for
>   a particular stack class instantiation, the standard container
>   std::deque is used.

All of which are heap based containers.

The following actually compiles ([clang](/questions/tagged/clang)):

```
std::stack<int, std::array<int, 12> > stack_of_months;
```

Until `push` is called.

Is there some trick to easily wrap the `std::array` to support those methodes so it may be used in the stack ?

Comment: No, because it doesn't support the `push` function. What's wrong with `vector`?

Comment: ok, so let's say you could do this with a `std::array`.  What would happen if you called `push` on a full stack?  An exception thrown, the element at the bottom gets removed, etc.?

Comment: @ChrisMM nothing is wrong with vector - I love vector - but suppose you need a limited stack based stack

Comment: Objects that store their data "on the stack" are implicitly fixed size in c++. `std::array` can't grow or shrink. You may be able to implement your own container if you know the maximum size you need to accommodate or are willing to arbitrarily set one. But it's generally unwise to store large pieces of data on the stack, it's a limited resource. It's easy to run out of stack space if you do that, and it's not recoverable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I would say it's an exception - push_back on a vector can also fail unless pre-allocated.

Comment: @darune Maybe using `std::vector` with stack-based allocator might work for you. But consider my previous warning about storing large data on the stack.

Comment: I guess it would be easy enough to write a small wrapper

Comment: @DanielLangr please post that as an answer

Comment: @darune -- I don't think that `boost::static_vector` uses the stack as storage though.  I think it maybe still using dynamic storage, but smartly puts a cap on the number of items, so if that's ok with you, then good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use Boost's [`static_vector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html):

> `static_vector` is a sequence container like with contiguous storage that can change in size, along with the **static allocation**, low overhead, and **fixed capacity**.

A working example:

```
std::stack<int, boost::container::static_vector<int, 4>> s;
s.push(1);
s.push(2);
s.push(3);
s.push(4);
// s.push(5); // would throw
```

---

@PaulMcKenzie And yes, it uses the stack as storage (if the object itself is stored in the stack, of course):

> The number of elements in a `static_vector` may vary dynamically up to a fixed capacity **because elements are stored within the object itself** similarly to an array.

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Gi40FrB0yX8dIwfA.

Comment: OK, I see that it has a template argument of `dtl::static_storage_allocator< Value, Capacity >`, which suggests it is using a static storage allocator.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't think you need to explore the source code to find this out. It's clearly written in the documentation and it's basically the main purpose of this container.

Comment: Didn't read the source code -- it's right there in the site you linked to on the second line.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok. My point is that the allocator class is from some implementation namespace `dtl`, so, IMO, it's better to read the documentation than to assume behavior according to some class name or its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be too hard to wrap a `std::array` into something usable by `std::stack`, you just need to keep track of how many elements have been pushed and popped:

```
#include <array>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>

template < typename T, size_t Size >
struct static_vector
{
  using value_type = T;
  using reference = T&;
  using const_reference = const T &;
  using size_type = size_t;

  static_vector()
    : size( 0 )
  {
  }

  std::array< T, Size > data;
  size_t size;

  void push_back( const_reference value )
  {
    data.at( size ) = value;
    size++;
  }

  void pop_back()
  {
    if ( size == 0 )
    {
      throw std::runtime_error( "empty" );
    }
    size--;
  }

  const_reference back() const
  {
    if ( size == 0 )
    {
      throw std::runtime_error( "empty" );
    }
    return data[ size - 1 ];
  }

  reference back()
  {
    if ( size == 0 )
    {
      throw std::runtime_error( "empty" );
    }
    return data[ size - 1 ];
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::stack< int, static_vector< int, 4 > > stack;
  stack.push( 1 );
  std::cout << stack.top() << "\n";
  stack.push( 2 );
  std::cout << stack.top() << "\n";
  stack.pop();
  std::cout << stack.top() << "\n";
  stack.pop();
}
```